# In the proof of the existence of $n^{\text{th}}$ roots (Rudin, Theorem 1.21), why is $y-k$ an upper bound of $E$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

After defining $E = \{ t > 0 : t^n < x\}$ and $y = \sup E$, Rudin first proves that the assumption $y^n < x$ leads to a contradiction. Then he continues

> Assume $y^n > x$. Put $$k = \frac{y^n-x}{ny^{n-1}}.$$
>    Then $0 < k < y$. It $t \geqslant y-k$, we conclude that $$y^n - t^n \leq y^n - (y-k)^n < kny^{n-1} = y^n-x.$$ Thus $t^n > x$, and $t\notin E$. It follows that $y-k$ is an upper bound of $E$.

On page 10, the last sentence, "If follows that $y-k$ is an upper bound of $E$". I do not understand how to get this point from $t\notin E$ and $t\ge y-k$. Could somebody help explain it to me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They assumed $t \geq y-k$ and then proved $t \notin E$. Therefore, we have:
$$t \geq y-k \implies t \notin E$$

In this case, you take the contrapositive and then get:
$$t \in E \implies t < y-k$$
Thus, all elements of $E$ are less than $y-k$, so $y-k$ is an upper bound of $E$.

Comment: Incidentally, was there any reason Rudin wrote $t \geq y-k$ rather than $t>y-k$? This leads to the more traditional definition of an upper bound as $t \in E \implies t \leq y-k$